# How to disable authentication and authorization in development environment in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC + Identity for authentication. I found some solution that suggest to comment the `//useAuthentication` or even the annotations, but I would like something that doesn't alter the controllers nor add comments.

Example of controller:

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  // [Authorize]
  public class UserController : ControllerBase

    [HttpGet()]
    //[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<UserGetResponseDto>>> GetMany()
    {
      return Ok(await _mediator.Send(new UserGetManyRequest()));
    }
```

Adding authentication in IdentityServiceRegistration:

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureIdentityServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
...
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
      {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      })
          .AddJwtBearer(o =>
          {
            o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
              ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
              ValidateIssuer = true,
              ValidateAudience = true,
              ValidateLifetime = true,
              ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
              ValidIssuer = configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
              ValidAudience = configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"],
              IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JwtSettings:Key"]))
            };
          });
...
```

Currently in Program.cs I have:

```
      //app.UseAuthorization();
```

but the UseAuthentication is handled in the ConfigureIdentityServices method above
If you guys know a way to implement it in .NET 7 instead of 6 that would serve too!

Comment: Based on your scenario and requirement, could you please share your full program.cs configuration along with controller details? That would helpful in order to investigate accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you are in the dev environment and only activate it in "production" e.g.

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

Comment: Server returns a `404 not found` if I comment the useAuthentication()

Comment: Can you provide more context to your question? 404 (NotFound) indicates that the route you want to access is not defined. Can you share more of your setup code and a minimal part of the controller or endpoint code?

Comment: If I run getUsers() with the annotations commented, it returns the list of users. If I uncomment the annotations, comment the useAuthentication and uncomment the useAuthorization I get 404

Comment: Is the Controller Route "hit" when the 404 is returned? Is the Mediator message sent?
Depending on what getUsers() is doing the problem might be there. If getUsers() fetches all the "users" currently accessible by the currently authenticated user this is "as designed". Since the `currently authenticated user` is "null". I am sorry but I think without more code/context it's hard to figure out.

Comment: For sure, since when the annotations are commented, it works